# Cannot get links to work on ul, others on page work fine

Tags: html, css

I am working on a school project so I am still learning how to code, but I am having problems getting the links to work in my ul.  The nav and other links on this page work fine, but this one doesnt work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is a link to the page and example of my coding.   http://www.nesbittclan.com/beatrice/treatments.html

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
<h1>Products</h1>
<li><a href="hair.html">Hair</a></li>
<li><a href="nails.html">Nails</a></li>
<li><a href="makeup.html">Makeup</a></li>
<li><a href="body.html">Body</a></li>
<h1>Treatments</h1>
<li><a href="massage.html">Massage</a></li>
<li><a href="nails.html">Nails</a></li>
<li><a href="makeup.html">Makeup</a></li>
<li><a href="laser.html">Laser Hair Removal/ Electrolysis</a></li>
<li><a href="facials.html">Facials</a></li>
<li><a href="packages.html">Packages</a></li>
<li><a href="special.html">Special Events</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, it's not valid HTML to have an <h1> tag as a direct descendant of a <ul>. You can however, have an <h1> tag within an <li>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all move `h1` tags somewhere, they can't be direct children of `UL` element.

But the real problem is not `a` tags actually, but weird styles for `<span>` under `#treatments h1` header tag:

```css
#treatments h1 span {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/treatmenttitle.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Since `h1` is positioned statically, span tag being positioned absolutely, overlays part of your page including `a` tags.

To fix the issue you can either position `span` relatively to parent `h1`:

```css
#treatments h1 {
    position: relative;
}
```

or remove `span` altogether, not sure if you need it at all.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
It worked, it was the coding with the #treatments h1. I thought I had it on there, but didn't. I had multiple pages with the span code, so just neglected this one. Thanks again!